# how to save regular expression extractor output in a file(csv or any other format) in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, export

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I m working on Jmeter.I build a script running for our Web Application

In one request i fetched a value from Http Response using Regular Expression Extractor..all well..

[image: RegEx_PRNumber]I want to save this value in a file(csv ,txt any format not an issue)

How this can be done in Jmeter

Thnks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To save the extracted value to a csv file follow the below procedure.

1. Remove Regex extractor as we will extract from the response using [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)
2. Add JSR223 Post Processor and paste the below code in the script section. Choose language as "`Groovy 2.4.12 / Groovy scripting engine 2.0`"

   ```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import java.io.FileWriter;
   import java.io.Writer;
   String stringToSearch=prev.getResponseDataAsString();
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile('value="(PR.+?)"');   
   Matcher match = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
   if (match.find()) {
       def value = match.group(1)
       log.info('------------------')
       log.info(value) // to check in the jmeter log for the extracted data
       vars.put('a', value) 
   }
   //get path of csv file (creates new one if its not exists)
   FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Tarik\\Desktop\\example.csv",true); // true to append
   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
   out.write(vars.get("a"));
   out.close();
   fileWriter.close();
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thank you.
Used 'println' instead of 'write' to have consecutive values in a new line.